# Increment form field value by one on submit form with Ajax cal

Tags: 8, forms

I have my custom form:

```
class MyCustomForm extends FormBase{

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'my_custom_form';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['point_field'] = [
      '#type' => 'value',
      '#markup' => '<span class="result_message">0</span>',
    ];

    $form['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#submit' => ['::addOne'],
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::setMessage',
      ],
    ];


    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * Submit handler for the "add-one-more" button.
   *
   * Increments the max counter and causes a rebuild.
   */
  public function addOne(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $point_field = $form_state->get('num_points');
    $add_button = $point_field + 1;
    $form_state->set('num_points', $add_button);

    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  /**
   *
   */
  public function setMessage(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(
      new HtmlCommand(
        '.result_message',
        '<div class="my_result">' . t('Results is @result', ['@result' => ($form_state->getValue('point_field') + 1)]) . '</div>')
    );
    return $response;

  }

  /**
   * @inheritDoc
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // TODO: Implement submitForm() method.
  }

}
```

When the user clicks the button, I want the `'point_field'` field value updates and increment by one, with an Ajax call.

Now it's adding just `1`. How do I build in a for loop, when the user keeps clicking the button it will increment by one? Then in the for loop I can control how many times the user can add a point... e.g. `$i<2`?

Comment: Hey meez, maybe have a look at Example module's [AjaxAddMore.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/examples/blob/8.x-1.x/form_api_example/src/Form/AjaxAddMore.php) and [AjaxColorForm.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/examples/blob/8.x-1.x/form_api_example/src/Form/AjaxColorForm.php) as starting point.

Comment: @leymannx I updated the question. Thanks again.

Comment: Try changing `$point_field = $form_state->get('num_points');` to `$point_field = ($form_state->get('num_points') ? (int) $form_state->get('num_points') : 0;`